# Is it possible to have other people remotely control my Macbook via another User Account?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, teamviewer, osx-el-capitan

I'm the sole Mac user in our small office of web developers. To do browser testing, they would have to ask for my permission to use my laptop. I read somewhere that it was possible to use Finder to remotely connect to another Macbook and log into another user account (so as not to disrupt whoever is using the laptop at the time). Is this same scenario also possible with Teamviewer (maybe perhaps a Pro account)?

Comment: There is [another option](https://www.browserstack.com/) and one that won't disrupt you from working.

Comment: I recommended it but none of them didn't wish to pay for the service and they find it really slow.

Comment: Get the company to pay. It can't be more than the cost of disrupting you every 10 minutes to allow your colleagues access to your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple users can remote log into both Apple's own built-in Screen Sharing & the Remote Desktop app - but it will drop the currently logged in user to the login screen on the remote machine.
You can log yourself back in after this happens, but I haven't really tested how much of a hit that will be on your frontmost user experience.

As far as I'm aware, VNC can do the same, but maximum 2 users. I can't test how many users can be done over Apple screen sharing, as we only have 2 Macs here.

As far as I'm aware, TeamViewer can only do the current frontmost user, but this is by no means an authoritative statement.